# Bootstrap tabs adding all content to 1 tab/pill

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im having issues with Bootstrap's pills. In particular im trying to dynamically add pills. I have this working however until a tab is clicked and triggered an event to change the active tab class all the dynamically added content appears on one single pill/tab.

```
<div id="exTab1" class="container-fluid">   
<ul  class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" id="tabTitles">
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="allTabs">      
</div>
```

This is my Javascript which im using to dynamically add content to:

```
Count++;
jQuery('<li/>', {
    id: 'li'+Count,
    rel: 'external',
    "class":"active",
    "data-toggle":"tab",
    "href":'#la'+Count
}).appendTo('#tabTitles');

jQuery('<a/>', {
    id: 'a'+Count,
    rel: 'external',
    "data-toggle":"tab",
    "html": title+Count
}).appendTo('#li'+Count);

jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'la'+Count,
    "class":"tab-pane active",
    "role":"tab"
}).appendTo('#allTabs');

jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'mynewDiv'+Count,
    rel: 'external',
    "class":"playground"
}).appendTo('#la'+Count);
```

All of this actually works, except the div "mynewDiv" or rather all the content at first appears on the same pill until i trigger an event which changes the class of the "li" to active:

```
function resetTabs(){
$('#tabTitles li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Is there a way to ensure only the most recently added pill's content is shown on the current active tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5kj0xtk)
.

I have created a jsFiddle here to replicate the behavior which you are asking.

Some points for why you are facing the issue:

1. While adding the  id: `'li'+Count,` element, you are making this pill active with `"class":"active",`. If there will be two pills with class active, both will be shown highlighted.
2. Similarly, while adding the pills' content, you are putting

   ```
   jQuery('<div/>', {
       id: 'la'+Count,
       "class":"tab-pane active",
       "role":"tab"
   }).appendTo('#allTabs');
   ```

which means you are setting the newly added pill's content active too, while still some other pill's content is in active state. That is why you are seeing all the pills content shown one below other.

To resolve the above issue. First, give the active class to only those pills or pills contents which you want to highlight. Only one at a time.

Based on my fiddle, i would suggest you to not give the active class while adding the pill or its content, and then at the last of you add method, just click programatically on the pill which you want to make active. It will deactivate other pills and make your pill highlighted with the desired content.

```
    $('#a'+Count).click();
```